# Rail premium Tatkal

Tags: tickets, indian-railways

I just booked a ticket from a travel agency. The travel agent gave me a pdf of that ticket which shows a total fare of 2490.56 INR.
When I checked the PNR inquiry from IRCTC App it shows 2049, which confused me.

Comment: The travel agent?

Comment: Could it be that the travel agent made a typo when entering the price?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.